# Store details from form into session for authentication

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file which I run locally which connects to an API. Currently I store the login details in a config file, but I don't want to do this.

Instead I want to present the user with a login form (with no backend, only JS) and have those credentials somehow stored with a reasonable level of security and used as the credentials for the API access, instead of using hardcoded ones.

Is this even possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Well, Jimmy, that's what databases are for.

Comment: You can store those details in localStorage or sessionStorage using javascript if you don't want to use a db. Better to do a hash and store in db, though.

Comment: So, the API *is* the backend that takes login details? Put an `<input>` in your page and have the user enter the API credentials.

Comment: You can't store them safely anywhere without a backend.

Comment: @Bergi That's what I want to go, but I don't want to use a server side language or store it in a database?

Comment: if you're willing to sacrifice "a reasonable level of security", you can definitely just do what @I.R.R. suggests and store the credentials in localstorage, but if you want to afford your users any kind of protection you will need a database

Comment: @Jimmy Ask the user for the credentials every time you call the API. Or store them in a local variable while the page is loaded. If you want to preserve it across page loads, see the duplicate for various options.